# Can't upgrade iPad to the latest build of iOS4.2

Tags: ipad, ios-4.2

I have upgraded my iPad to iOS4.2 (gold master 8C134) but I didn't upgrade to the second gold master 8C134b.
Now that iOS4.2 has been made available on iTune, the gold master image has been removed off the developer account, but I am stuck in the 8C134 build of iOS4.2
iTune check for update doesn't recognize that I don't have the latest build.

Any idea how to upgrade to 8C134b, thx

Comment: You could do a full (factory) reset and upgrade from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the [4.2.1 image directly](http://osxdaily.com/2010/11/22/ios-4-2-direct-download/) from Apple.  They just don't make the link easy to find for some reason.  I expected it to be in the developer portal.  Silly me!